# setting soft limit for 4store client

Tags: sparql, 4store

While running the sparql queries I get the warning

```
    # hit complexity limit 20 times, increasing soft limit may give more results
```

and this is not dependent to any particular query but for all.I wanted to know how can I increase the soft limit if I am not using the http interface rather I am using the 4store client master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default 4store gives a soft limit of about 1000. You have a couple of options to tweak/disable search breadth:

- If using 4s-query you can override the setting with `--soft-limit` e.g. `4s-query --soft-limit 5000 demo 'SELECT ... etc.'`. Setting it to `-1` completely disables it.
- If using a 3rd party client you can tweak soft limit with a cgi parameter e.g. `sparql-query 'http://example.org/sparql/?soft-limit=-1'`
- You can set the soft limit globally when starting the sparql server with the `-s` parameter. See `4s-httpd --help`.